# use stdClass in class as class var in php 5+

Tags: php

I can't seem to get this right.. It seems I keep creating a new `stdClass` when I'm tryng to add to what should be one for the scope.

```
    class d_elem {
        private $el;
        function __constructor($p) {
            $el = new stdClass;
        }
        private static function ele_base($p) {
            print('ele_base<br/>');
            d_elem::ele_base_attr($p);
        }
        private static function ele_base_attr($p) {
            print('ele_base_attr<br/>');
            isset($p['id']) ? $el->id = '' . $p['id'] . '' : '';
            print_r($p);print('<br/>');
            print_r($el);print('<br/>'); //<< should have added the id but created a new one????
        }
        public static function ele_a($p) {
            d_elem::ele_base($p);
            isset($p['href']) ? $el->href = '' . $p['href'] . '' : '';
            isset($p['TEXT']) ? $el->TEXT = '' . $p['TEXT'] . '' : '';
            print_r($p);print('<br/>');
            print_r($el);print('<br/>');//<< should have added the id but only has the href and TEXT when all 3 should be there
            //skip the retrun
        }
    }

    echo d_elem::ele_a(array('href'=>"#",'TEXT'=>'test','id'=>'test'));
```

Any one have an idea?

thank you -Jeremy

[EDIT]--------------------------------------
per the suggestion above

```
    class d_elem{
        public static $el;
        private static function init(){ 
            self::$el = new stdClass; 
        } 
        private static function ele_base($p) {
            print('ele_base<br/>');
            self::ele_base_attr($p);
        }
        private static function ele_base_attr($p) {
            print('ele_base_attr<br/>');
            isset($p['id']) ? $el->id = '' . $p['id'] . '' : '';
            print_r($el);print('<br/>'); //<< should have added the id but created a new one????
        }
        public static function ele_a($p) {
            self::init();
            self::ele_base($p);
            isset($p['href']) ? $el->href = '' . $p['href'] . '' : '';
            isset($p['TEXT']) ? $el->TEXT = '' . $p['TEXT'] . '' : '';
            print_r($el);print('<br/>');
            //skip the retrun
        }
    }

    d_elem::ele_a(array('href'=>"#",'TEXT'=>'test','id'=>'test'));
```

Still produces the same output of

ele_base

ele_base_attr

stdClass Object ( [id] => test )

stdClass Object ( [href] => # [TEXT] => test )

.

and want

stdClass Object (  [id] => test [href] => # [TEXT] => test )

tk -J

**[END SOLUTION AS OF YET]**

```
        class d_elem {
            private static $el;  /// fill this as we run from function to function
            private static function init(){ // start off but creating the object
                self::$el = new stdClass; 
            } 
            private static function ele_base($p) {
                self::ele_base_attr($p);// here we fill base on some condition.. simple test first
            }
            private static function ele_base_attr($p) {
                isset($p['id']) ? self::$el->id = ' id="' . $p['id'] . '" ' : '';  // this should be pushed to the class level object
            }
            public static function ele_a($p) {
                $p=!is_array($p)?get_object_vars ($p):$p; // make sure that if p is an object we trun it to an array
                self::init();// set the class object
                self::ele_base($p);// make first add to class object
                isset($p['href']) ? self::$el->href = ' href="' . $p['href'] . '" ' : ''; make second add to the class object
                foreach (self::$el as $key => $value) {
                    $ele .= $value; // spit the values back out to return from the class object
                }
                $ele .= $p['TEXT'] ; // test something to return at this level 
                return $ele // return all the properties in this case a string of them
            }
        }

        echo d_elem::ele_a(array('href'=>"#",'TEXT'=>'test','id'=>'test')); // call for the output
```

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `$el = new stdClass;` should be `$el = new stdClass();`

Comment: @RafeKettler it doesn't matter in PHP at all

Comment: @Ondrej Slinták I want to keep adding to $el as i move thru the functions.  I don't want to pass it thro as I'm looking for a simple way to hold the info.  Hope the makes sense here I did comment the code to help better I hope. tk -J

Comment: @RafeKettler ; Strangely, `$el = new stdClass;` works the same way that `$el = new stdClass();` does.. but I suppose the latter is the better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fix everything, but a few things to note:

`__constructor()` never gets called, because the class never gets instantiated, only called statically (and should be called `__construct()`).

There's no need to `echo d_elem::elem_a()` because nothing is returned.

If you want to use the function as static functions, the `$el` variable also needs to be static, and referred to as `self::$el`. Similarly, when calling static functions inside the object you should call them as `self::ele_base_attr()` etc.

---

EDIT: You could turn the __construct into a static function, ie:

```
private static function init()
{
    self::$el = new stdClass;
}
```

Then call `self::init()` before doing anything else in `d_elem::elem_a()`.

---

EDIT: This achieves the same thing:

```
class d_elem {
    public static $el;

    public static function ele_a($p) {
        self::$e = new stdClass;

        if(isset($p['href'])) $el->href = $p['href'];
        if(isset($p['TEXT'])) $el->TEXT = $p['TEXT'];
        if(isset($p['id'])) $el->id = $p['id'];

        print_r(self::$el);
    }
}

d_elem::ele_a(array('href'=>"#",'TEXT'=>'test','id'=>'test'));
```

Comment: well few things on this.. echo d_elem::elem_a() was just to call it in to action.. echo is the not needed part :D .. self:: and su_elements:: worked the same.. can't beleive I missed the typo but oldly changeing it to public function __construct(){
    print('test<br/>');
    $el = new stdClass();
   }   didn't help .. not sure.. didn't even get the print..

Comment: But as I said, __construct() is never called, because the class is never instantiated.

Comment: ok.. so doing what I really really don't want to do instantiate $Ele=new d_elem();  
echo $Ele->ele_a(array('href'=>"#",'TEXT'=>'test','id'=>'test'));  still doesn't solve the issues.. I really don't want to have to put $Ele=new d_elem(); everywhere too.. has to be a simple way to do this lol. tk -J

Comment: ok adding a answer as it's to long.. per what I think you suggested.

Comment: You still need to change the references to $el to self::$el within your functions.

Comment: so yes adding that does work.. tk .. I got to wounder if there is a shorter way.. :? oh well it works.. if there is a better way then I'm all ears :D .. tk for the help.. -J

Comment: **NOTE TO OTHERS:** I need to clear this.. **JUST TO BE CLEAR FOR OTHERS last edit does not do the same thing only achives the same result of the test code shorter**. We have to remeber yes I could pull it in to on function but that was not the question, the little test peice is just a slice of the whole model.  In this case it needs to run thru a few functions and so that is why I wanted to get to and set the class scoped var even if static.  Would still love a better anwser then what I have above. Very open but needs to work much the same with boucing around from function to function.  tk -J

Comment: You asked for a shorter way, so I gave a shorter way! Without knowing exactly what you want (I'm still not entirely sure) it's very difficult to give the right answer. You're on your own...

Comment: fair enough.. I was not clear in the main post only in the comment to the post that it needed to have the functions there and bounce around in there.. :D But also why I Noted to others

Answer (score 0):

See [$this](http://php.net/%24this) and [self](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), also [late static bindings](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: I don't see how this helps.. you can't do $this->el->id as this is a using $this when not in object context so that would be a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
isset($p['id']) ? $this->el->id = '' . $p['id'] . '' : '';
```

And this?:

```
print_r($this->el);print('<br/>');
```

Within a class, for you to access variables declared (for the entire class to use like `$el`) from within methods/functions within that same class, you'll need the change `$el` (or any variable of the same scope) to `$this->el`

Comment: as per the other comment I left "you can't do $this->el->id as this is a using $this when not in object context so that would be a fatal error" so needs to be something else.. tk -J